# Dual authentication works on 2.29.0 but fails on 2.30.0 and beyond with SASL error for ActiveMQ Artemis Docker

Tags: activemq-artemis

We are currently running ActiveMQ Artemis 2.29.0 in a Docker container on AWS ECS and have dual authentication set up. Our `broker.xml` file is fairly simple. We have one acceptor on port `5671`:

```xml
<acceptor name="amqps">tcp://0.0.0.0:5671?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/data/certs/apache-activemq-artemis-keystore.ks;keyStorePassword=REPLACE_WITH_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD;trustStorePath=/data/certs/apache-activemq-artemis-truststore.ts;trustStorePassword=REPLACE_WITH_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD;enabledProtocols=TLSv1.2;tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;handshake-timeout=0</acceptor>
```

We copy this file over during the Docker image build process and our `docker-run.sh` is almost identical to Apache's. At the end of the file we have

```bash
echo "Copying our broker configuration to ${CONFIG_PATH}"
cp $BROKER_XML "${CONFIG_PATH}/broker.xml"

echo "Executing ./bin/artemis $@"
exec ./bin/artemis "$@"
```

On 2.29.0 our dual authentication is successful. We are using the latest version of the `rhea` npm module to connect our Node.js micro-services to the broker. When I upgrade to 2.30.0 and above, the micro-services are not able to connect to the broker, they throw the following error:

```
2024-01-19T15:41:59.574Z amqpConnector:debug Connection to the AMQP broker was disconnected ProtocolError: SASL layer not enabled
    at Transport.read (/src/node_modules/rhea/lib/transport.js:87:27)
    at Connection.input (/src/node_modules/rhea/lib/connection.js:567:37)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:545:12)
    at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:495:3)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:375:5)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

Based on the [examples for 2.31.2](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis-examples/tree/main/examples/features/standard/ssl-enabled-dual-authentication), it looks like it should work. I read the [release notes](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/release-notes-2.30.0) and didn't read about anything that would cause a breakage in dual authentication. What am I missing? Is this a bug I should report?

Comment: Can you reproduce the failure on bare metal (i.e. outside of Docker)?

Comment: Have you tried passing `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` to the broker's JVM and seeing what it says?

Comment: How would I do this? Would I add that to the exec command? `exec ./bin/artemis "$@" -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` Like that?

Comment: You can add system properties to the JVM by modifying `etc/artemis.profile`.

Comment: Sorry, I've been pulled in a different direction but as soon as I get a chance I will provide the feedback from updating that file.

Comment: I added the java args and I found the relevant error, but I'm confused as to why it's working on 2.29 and not on 2.30 and beyond. `Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed (` and further down I see `Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Fri Sep 03 14:19:50 UTC 2021`

Comment: You should add these details to the body of your question. Include the full stack-trace if you can.

Comment: Although the SSL/TLS configuration is done mostly in `broker.xml` the broker delegates all SSL/TLS functionality to the underlying JVM. I'm not aware of any broker-level configuration that can impact certificate expiration. If the JVM says the cert is expired then my only conclusion is that it must be. My guess is that either the certificates or the JVM are different in the two environments.

Comment: I created new certificates, a new keystore for artemis, kept the same truststore. Now I'm getting this error `2024-01-31 22:03:12,909 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222208: SSL handshake failed for client from /172.23.0.103:57772: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.` I verified that the new certificates work with Artemis 2.29.0

Comment: Can you work up a way to reproduce what you're seeing with self-signed certificates? At this point it looks like a misconfiguration of some kind on 2.30.0. Are both of these brokers using the JVM version? As noted previously, the broker isn't involved in the SSL handshake process. That's delegated to the JVM.

Comment: I am using self-signed certificates. The JDK version 2.29.0 is using in my container is `openjdk version "11.0.22" 2024-01-16` and 2.30.0 uses `jdk-11.0.20+8`

Comment: Please provide a way to reproduce what you're seeing on ActiveMQ Artemis 2.30.0.

Comment: So, it looks like 2.32.0 fixed the issue. I just tried with the same configuration except updated the Dockerfile to use `FROM apache/activemq-artemis:2.32.0` which uses and updated version of JDK and my micro-service connect successfully.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what specific change would have fixed the issue for you. It would still be nice to have a way to reproduce what you were seeing on 2.30.0 so I could investigate further to ensure such a problem doesn't arise again.

Comment: I created the certificates with openssl, then combined the key and cert with `openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey infrastructure.KEY.pem -in infrastructure.CERTIFICATE.pem -name 'wildcard.infrastructure' -out broker-2024.p12` . I used the same CA I had and used the same method for the Truststore. The broker is using service discovery on AWS and is running as a Docker container.